# what is wrong with the else statement , i am converting string to int to string to linked list

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, singly-linked-list

If we have a linked list and pointer to its head. Linked list represent a number. Then add `1` to the number and output the new linked list. For ex `2->6->9` ie `269` should output `270` ie `2->7>0`.

My code is running fine when there is no carry, but not otherwise.

I am first taking the number in a string, converting it to a number and converting it back to a string creating the new linked list of the resultant after adding `1` to it.

```
Node* addOne(Node *head) 
    {
        Node*ptr=head;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL){
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        if(ptr->data<9){
        ptr->data=ptr->data+1;
        }
        else{
            ptr=head;
            string s="";
            while(ptr!=NULL){
                int data=ptr->data;
                s=s+to_string(data);
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            int x;
            x=stoi(s);
            x++;
            s=to_string(x);
            int n=s.length();
            Node*head2=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
            Node*ptr2=head2;
            int i=0;
            ptr2->data=s[i];
            ptr2->next=NULL;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                Node*temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
                temp->data=s[i];
                ptr2->next=temp;
                temp->next=NULL;
                ptr2=ptr2->next;
            }
            return head2;
        }
        return head;
        
    }
```

Input :

```
369
```

Ouput:

```
515548
```

Expected Output:

```
370
```

Comment: That's a big blob of code with little whitespace, some C-style code (why `malloc` instead of `new`) and some big memory leaks (I see `malloc`s but not `free`s). But since you're going through the nodes anyway to find the last one, consider putting them on a stack. If the top element is 9, set to 0 and set the carry flag, otherwise increase by one. Then go down the stack and do the same, until you run out of carries. That will cover almost all cases except `9 -> 9 -> 9 -> .. -> .9`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create any nodes, unless the carry makes the number go from 99 to 100, or 999 to 1000, etc..

Comment: *My code is running fine when there is no carry but not otherwise* -- "My car runs fine, except when I need to make right turns".  Never say "your code runs fine, except..." -- this means your code is not running fine.  Saying "your code runs fine" gives the impression it needs just a line or two of code to change.  What if what makes the code "run fine" requires a total redesign?

Comment: Welcome at the stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and then provide [mcve]. I recommend provide a link to some online compiler for example: https://godbolt.org/z/jhsfq41rf